# How do I extract data from pptx file using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, text-extraction

I am using XSLFPowerPointExtractor to extract text from a pptx file. However all the text in the pptx file is returned to me in a single string. Is there anyway i can get the text on each slide separately? I am completely new to this concept, so please give detailed answers..

Comment: Have you looked into apache poi?

Comment: yes, powerpointextractor is a class of the POI package. it just gives me the getText() option which returns the entire content of the file as a string.

Comment: Did you look at the format of the returned string? I would assume the slides would be delimited somehow, and you could split the string on the delimiter.

Comment: i did, there is no way to tell one slide apart from the other. its all one long string.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the API documentation and it seems that it's either all or nothing. The [API documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/extractor/XSLFPowerPointExtractor.html) has a method called getText() which returns the entire text for all the slides which is exactly the behavior you are observing.

A bit more googling showed me that the way to do it is to use another API namely [XMLSlideShow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XMLSlideShow.html). That gives you a slide-by-slide access to the presentation.

From there, you can access the different shapes including the text areas from which you can read the text. As a matter of fact, this is explained in this other SO question which I believe will help you resolve your issue: [How to get pptx slide notes text using apache poi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873725/how-to-get-pptx-slide-notes-text-using-apache-poi)